# How to transform XML to text

Tags: python, lxml

Following on from my earlier question ([how to transform XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31260522/how-to-transform-xml/31264113#31264113)), I now have a nicely structured XML doc, like this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<employee id="1" reportsTo="1" title="CEO">
    <employee id="2" reportsTo="1" title="Director of Operations">
        <employee id="3" reportsTo="2" title="Human Resources Manager" />
    </employee>
</employee>
</root>
```

Now I need to convert it to javascript like this..

```
var treeData = [
{
"name": "CEO",
"parent": "null",
"children": [
  {
    "name": "Director of Operations",
    "parent": "Top Level",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Human Resources Manager",
        "parent": "Level 2: A"
      }
   ]
  }
]
}
];
```

I've started writing an XSLT, which currently looks like this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="employee" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="employee">
    <xsl:param name="eId" select="@id" />
    <xsl:param name="eReports" select="@reportsTo" />
    <xsl:param name="eTitle" select="@title" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat( $eTitle, ' and ', $eId )" />      
    <xsl:apply-templates select="employee" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But when I apply the transform (via pythons lxml library), I get the message "None". 
(In case it helps, here's the lxml command I'm using...)

```
dom = ET.parse("input.xml")
xslt = ET.parse("transform.xslt")
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)
print(ET.tostring(newdom, pretty_print=True))
```

I know my XSLT is nowhere near complete, but why aren't I getting *any* output? Shouldn't I at least be getting the job title printed?

Comment: "*why aren't I getting any output?*" Your problem cannot be reproduced using the code you have posted.

Comment: The result using your current code is: `"CEO and 1Director of Operations and 2Human Resources Manager and 3"`.

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k I stil get "None" on my machine. I think my problem might be with the way I'm using the transform in lxml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: updated now that OP's included his Python code.

Your problem is that `lxml.etree.tostring` and also the `.write` method are only meaningful on XML, not on an XSLT result with `output method="text"` which might not have a single root element like XML does. For some confusing reason, the functions *do* have a `method=` keyword argument but it does not do anything useful.

This is what you should do:

```
import lxml.etree as etree
data = etree.parse('data.xml')
transform = etree.XSLT(etree.parse('txt.xslt'))
res = transform(data)
bytes(res)
```

```
b'\nCEO and 1Director of Operations and 2Human Resources Manager and 3\n'
```

If you're interested in a real world example, [I recently made a patch.](https://github.com/JukkaL/mypy/pull/713/files#diff-45891072f20ac836651c941196a8aa0bR248)

Comment: Sorry. I edited my code before posting. Will amend question with more parameters in the concat function.

Comment: @LucienStals updated, still not `None`. You really should have included your python code too.

Comment: Thank you! And all along I thought it was my crappy understanding of XSLT that was at fault. Turns out it's my crayy understanding of lxml. The world is a better place now.