# XSLT 2.0 - How to transform a flat XML structure to a nested/hierarchical XML structure

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to transform the following flat XML structure to a nested/hierarchical XML structure using XSLT 2.0.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
    <productlist>
        <product id="prod_lmo" parent-id="product_family"><prodname>LMO</prodname></product>
        <product id="prod_sdf" parent-id="product_family"><prodname>SDF</prodname></product>
        <product id="prod_sdfg" parent-id="prod_sdf"><prodname>SDFg</prodname></product>
        <product id="prod_abc123" parent-id="prod_abc"><prodname>ABC-123</prodname></product>
        <product id="prod_sdfh" parent-id="prod_sdfg"><prodname>SDF-h</prodname></product>
        <product id="prod_family" parent-id="root"><prodname>Product Family</prodname></product>
        <product id="prod_sdfj" parent-id="prod_sdfh"><prodname>SDF-j</prodname></product>
        <product id="prod_lmao" parent-id="prod_lmo"><prodname>LMAO</prodname></product>
        <product id="prod_elo" parent-id="product_family"><prodname>ELO</prodname></product>
        <product id="prod_lmfao" parent-id="prod_lmo"><prodname>LMFAO</prodname></product>
        <product id="prod_abc" parent-id="product_family"><prodname>ABC</prodname></product>
    </productlist>
</products>
```

Using the parent-id attribute of each  element I want to create a nested hierarchy. If the parent-id attribute value of a  element matches the id attribute of another  element - then it becomes the child of that  element.

This is want I to achieve:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
    <productlist>
        <product id="product_family" parent-id="root"><prodname>Product Family</prodname>
            <product id="prod_elo" parent-id="product_family"><prodname>ELO</prodname></product>
            <product id="prod_lmo" parent-id="product_family"><prodname>LMO</prodname>
                <product id="prod_lmao" parent-id="prod_lmo"><prodname>LMAO</prodname></product>
                <product id="prod_lmfao" parent-id="prod_lmo"><prodname>LMFAO</prodname></product>
            </product>
            <product id="prod_sdf" parent-id="product_family"><prodname>SDF</prodname>
                <product id="prod_sdfg" parent-id="prod_sdf"><prodname>SDFg</prodname>
                    <product id="prod_sdfh" parent-id="prod_sdfg"><prodname>SDF-h</prodname>
                        <product id="prod_sdfj" parent-id="prod_sdfh"><prodname>SDF-j</prodname></product>
                    </product>
                </product>
            </product>        
            <product id="prod_abc" parent-id="product_family"><prodname>ABC</prodname>
                <product id="prod_abc123" parent-id="prod_abc"><prodname>ABC-123</prodname></product>
            </product>
        </product>
    </productlist>
</products>
```

I have looked at using keys and for-each-group, but I can't figure out how to apply them and the necessary recursion. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="children" match="product" use="@parentid"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="products/productlist">
    <products>
      <productlist>
        <xsl:for-each select="product[@parentid='root']">
          <product>
            <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="pid"><xsl:value-of select="@parentid"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:copy-of select="prodname"/>
            
            <xsl:for-each select="key('children', @id)">              
              <product>
                <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="pid"><xsl:value-of select="@parentid"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:copy-of select="prodname"/>
                
                <xsl:for-each select="key('children', @id)">
                  <product>
                    <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="pid"><xsl:value-of select="@parentid"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="prodname"/>
                    
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('children', @id)">
                      <product>
                        <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="pid"><xsl:value-of select="@parentid"/></xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="prodname"/>    
                      </product>             
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    
                  </product>             
                </xsl:for-each>
              </product>             
            </xsl:for-each>
                
          </product>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </productlist>
    </products>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which NOW works after some sharp eyes from Martin Honnen! - to correct the id attribute value from `prod_family` to `product_family`.

Comment: A key sounds fine and recursion in XSLT comes in easy if you apply-templates to the items selected by the `key` function call. So spell out your attempt at that if you can't get it to solve the problem, post your attempt and how it fails.

Comment: Additionally, in your result sample you start with `<product id="prod_family"` but then have children with e.g. `parent-id="product_family"`. How do you expect a key or a programmatic cross-reference in any way to match on those two values?

Comment: See the example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31213727/3016153

Comment: Many thanks Martin for spotting the above error/typo - I spent hours previously trying to get it to work.
However, the next question is - what's the most efficient way to implement nesting of the hierarchy as having many ` <xsl:for-each select="key('children', @id)">` statements requires you to know the depth of the hierarchy beforehand?

Answer (score 1):

The recursion, as I said in a comment, is done with apply-templates:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
  
  <xsl:key name="child" match="product" use="@parent-id"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="productlist">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', 'root')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="product">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node(), key('child', @id)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```